# Image (color?) segmentation with opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-segmentation

[image: http://i.imgur.com/iIv4gJa.png]

As the graph showed, I'd like to input image and get several segments as a result like that.

It's just like cluster the closest color segment, so I think it's close to the concept of "meanshift"?

I've searched relevant questions here but still don't know how to start and construct the structure in opencv C++. I'm looking for some advises, and I'll be very appreciate if getting a piece of implementation code for me to reference! Thanks for any help!!

==================================================

Edit 5/19/2015

Let me add that one of my trying implementations is Watershed here:(http://blog.csdn.net/fdl19881/article/details/6749976).

[image]

It's not perfect but the result i want. In this implement, user needs to operate manually( draw the watershed lines ), so i'm looking for AUTOMATIC version of it. Sounds a little bit hard, but... i'll appreciate for some suggestion or piece of code to do it.

Comment: Please post any code efforts you made.

Comment: Maybe you could use an watershed algorithm for the segmentation, and select the average color from the segmented element for the visualization?! That's how i would start

Comment: Actually, I'd tried several implementation searched on the net, but seems like no even one close to what i want except Efficient Graph-Based Image Segmentation (by P. Felzenszwalb, D. Huttenlocher), here is the demo site: http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/segment/ 
But unfortunately, I got a problem in this code patch(the "loadPPM" function in it), so I came here begging for some other/modified way to implement.

Comment: @retinotop yeah you're right! That's what i try to do now, but the "watershed" implementation i saw are needed to work MANUALLY but not AUTOMATIC segment...

Answer (score 4):

Opencv Documentation: [Link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=pyrmeanshiftfiltering)

Parameters: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raNaT.png)

Sample code for Meanshift filtering:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat img, res, element;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

   namedWindow( "Meanshift", 0 );
   img = imread( argv[1] );
// GaussianBlur(img, img, Size(5,5), 2, 2);
   pyrMeanShiftFiltering( img, res, 20, 45, 3);
   imwrite("meanshift.png", res);
   imshow( "Meanshift", res );

   waitKey();

   return 0;
}
```

This is the output with your image, you might need to use some pre-processing before or maybe find some better parameters:

[image: output]

EDIT: Output with some gaussian blur beforehand (comment in code)

[image: here]

Comment: This is so close to what i want! But i gonna try to adjust the parameters to make it more smoothly!(to make the segment area size well situated) Actually this color segmentation is the preceding operation of "semantic segmentation", so i'll consider carefully doing blur or not to prevent destroy the local feature information in it.

Comment: @Oasis is you want super-pixels for semantic segmentation you might want to consider more modern approaches such as [slic](http://ivrl.epfl.ch/research/superpixels)

Comment: @Oasis If you are looking for mean-shift **segmentation** (rather than **filtering**) you might want to consider [EDISON](http://coewww.rutgers.edu/riul/research/code/EDISON/).

Comment: @Oasis, Efficient Graph Based Segmentation is a quite good algorithm, if you are in linux you can try `convert image.anything image.ppm`. Theres also a pretty good port to opencv in [link](http://subokita.com/2014/04/24/efficient-graph-based-image-segmentation-by-felzenszwalb-and-huttenlocher/).

Comment: @melchizedek So pity i'm in Windows that i don't know what to do... I got the advanced version( can read any file format but not just for .PPM) of it, but there are still some errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with looking at existing segmentation approaches is that they are either implemented in Matlab (which nobody outside of Uni can use) or they are not automatic. An approach where the user needs to preprocess the picture by choosing objects of interest or levels that indicate how to split colors is not useful because it is not automatic. If you like, you can try my OpenCV based implementation of segmentation described in this [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post14_OpenCV_segmentation/index.html). It is not perfect, but it is automatic and does most of the job and you can actually download the source and try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately this blog post is gone. It is [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20180608100956/http://www.modejong.com/blog/post14_OpenCV_segmentation/index.html) but without any of the images.